# Attach div content to email body

Tags: javascript, html, html-email

I am trying to add a content inside a div as the body for an email content. Here is the tagfor html email button.

```
<a href="mailto:?Subject=I found these breweries&amp;Body='I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 '">
```

So how do I add the content inside the div to the body of the email ?

Comment: Okay. what is your question?

Comment: You mean you want to append some data to body of email?

Comment: Yes I would like to append the data from the div to the body of that email.

Comment: Javascript doesnt work on emails. Which email client are you targeting?

Comment: deleting my answer as @Syfer told me . since my answer will not work for OP

Comment: This is what I get :'I saw this and thought of you!  '<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'><tr><th>Name</th><td>Bitter Sisters Brewing Company</td></tr><tr><th>Type</th><td>Micro</td></tr><tr><th>Address</th><td>15103 Surveyor Blvd Addison, TX 75001-4316 </td></tr><table><hr><table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'><tr><th>Name</th><td>Bitter Sisters Brewing Company</td></tr><tr><th>Type</th><td>Micro</td></tr><tr><th>Address</th></tr><table><hr>

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible, with the mailto: function here it opens a new email with prefiled text in. 
This way only takes plain text, so no div, h1 or any other html tags.